# Displaying header data on google

Tags: php, wordpress, meta

This is my site:

http://www.armonisencia.cl/site/

When you search "armonisencia" on Google, it displays the following (you can see it on the attached picture too):

"Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ...
www.armonisencia.cl/site/
Traducir esta páginaFatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function elegant_description() in /home/armonisencia/public_html/site/wp-content/themes/DIVI/header.php:16 Stack trace: #0 /home/armonisencia/public_html/site/wp-includes/template.php(688): require_once() #1 ..."

Maybe is some bug in my WordPress or something, but i decided i didn't want to look for the solution and i prefered to do the more simple stuff, i just edited my theme's header.php file and left the head element like this:

```html
    <head>
<title>Armonisencia</title>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="description" content="Naturaleza que funciona">
 <meta name="keywords" content="Productos, Armonisencia">

 

 <?php $template_directory_uri = get_template_directory_uri(); ?>
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <script src="<?php echo esc_url( $template_directory_uri . '/js/html5.js"' ); ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <![endif]-->

 <script type="text/javascript">
  document.documentElement.className = 'js';
 </script>

 <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
```

I made this change yesterday and today Google is still showing me the same ulgy data. How can i fix it?

This is how  looked before my change

```html
<head>
 <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
 <?php elegant_description(); ?>
 <?php elegant_keywords(); ?>
 <?php elegant_canonical(); ?>

 <?php do_action( 'et_head_meta' ); ?>

 <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>" />

 <?php $template_directory_uri = get_template_directory_uri(); ?>
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <script src="<?php echo esc_url( $template_directory_uri . '/js/html5.js"' ); ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <![endif]-->

 <script type="text/javascript">
  document.documentElement.className = 'js';
 </script>

 <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
```

[image: the error]

Answer (score 0):

The excerpt shown by google tells you where the error is:

*"Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function elegant_description() in /home/armonisencia/public_html/site/wp-content/themes/DIVI/header.php:16 Stack trace: #0 /home/armonisencia/public_html/site/wp-includes/template.php(688): require_once() #1 .."*

It saying that you're trying to use a function (*elegant_description()*) in your header.php that doesn't exist.

Google crawls websites to scrape information however it doesn't happen instantly (in fact it can take up to 30 days). You can request google to crawl your site again via Google search console. Here is a support doc by Google that will get you going in the right direction: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6065812?hl=en

Comment: I edited my question adding how the header.php file looked before.

Comment: The removal of the elegant_description function most-likely solves your issue (check for more errors in your local copy just in case of more depreciated functions) however you will still need to request another crawl for google to reindex your page with the updated header.